# Definition of Mean Square Error for a vector of Paraneters

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

In the Book "Introduction to Linear Regression Analysis", second edition by Montgomery et al, I found on page 306 in Ridge estimation:

The Mean Square Error (MSE) of Ridge Estimator is defined as
\begin{equation}
\mbox{MSE}[\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_R] = \sigma^2\mbox{Trace}[\{X'X+k\mathrm{I}\}^{-1}X'X\{X'X+k\mathrm{I}\}^{-1}] + k^2\boldsymbol{\beta}'\{X'X+k\mathrm{I}\}^{-2}\boldsymbol{\beta}.
\end{equation}
Above expression is obtained if the MSE is defined as
\begin{equation}
(a) \qquad \mbox{MSE}[\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_R] = \mathbb{E}[\{\mathbb{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_R - \boldsymbol{\beta}\}'\{\mathbb{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_R - \boldsymbol{\beta}\}].
\end{equation}

In the same book I found this on page 330, subset selection:
\begin{equation}
\mbox{MSE}[\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_p] = \sigma^2(X_p'X_p)^{-1} + A\boldsymbol{\beta}_r\boldsymbol{\beta}_r'A'
\end{equation}
Above expression is obtained if the MSE is defined as
\begin{equation}
(b) \qquad \mbox{MSE}[\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_R] = \mathbb{E}[\{\mathbb{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_R - \boldsymbol{\beta}\}\{\mathbb{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_R - \boldsymbol{\beta}\}'].
\end{equation}
So, which definition of MSE is correct? (a) or (b)?

Comment: I would assume that the difference is only that in (a) $\mathbf{\beta}$ and $\mathbf{\beta}_R$ are column vectors, and in (b) they are defined as row vectors. MSE has to be a scalar.